# Is the objective of a verb 'dump' suitable for a waste(trash) which was thrown by a person?

Tags: verbs

According to Oxford, a verb 'dump' means

> dump something to get rid of something you do not want, especially in a place that is not suitable
>
> > Too much toxic waste is being dumped at sea.

> > The dead body was just dumped by the roadside.

> > Any vessel dumping at sea without a licence will be prosecuted.

Reading the examples, I think that the objective of this verb should be large amount(or bulky volume) of waste.
Because, in general, 'toxic waste'  can be wasted by a factory or a company, not an individual in the 1st sentence.
and a 'vessel' might have thrown enoumous mount of garbage, not small-sized one.

Is it suitable to use this verb 'dump' for a case that an individual let a plastic bag filled with garbage on a street, or inside a park?

If not, would you recommend some alternatives?

Comment: Well, I just dumped a gallon of used paint thinner in the gutter.  Does that make me a "company"?  And the I dumped a bag of banana peels in the middle of the sidewalk.

Comment: And I went into the local convenience store and dumped out my coffee mug in the sink before refilling it.  While outside there was a guy dumping an ash tray on the pavement.

Comment: "To dump" = to deposit (any amount of anything) casually, negligently or without ceremony or formality.. I can see no connection with a large amount. *The Story of Two Jakes* by Merlin C. Williams "When the water and corn boiled, he dumped the venison in to the pot." Obviously there was no great quantity of venison.

Comment: Along the lines of @Greybeard: There is nothing in the definition you cite that implies large amount or bulky quantity. Last night, some jerk dumped some crap on my front lawn, e.g., a few beer bottles and bags of McDonald's refuse. They got rid of something they didn't want in a place that was not suitable, at least as far as my front lawn was concerned.

Comment: And of course, if you dumped your girlfriend, she would not only be upset but insulted as well because you implied she was 'large'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have suggested, it is natural to use the verb 'dump' for disposing of a quantity of unwanted objects in a careless or unceremonious way.

Your example of 'he dumped his garbage on the street' sounds perfectly natural to me.

This is nuanced, but it feels a little unnatural to use 'dump' if you mean 'improperly disposing of a single small object', for example
'he dumped his book in the street' sounds slightly strange to me. But if the single object is large or cumbersome, such as a body, then it is fine.

It would be natural to say 'he dumped his books', (plural) 'he dumped his coffee', (liquids or objects from a container) 'he dumped his french fries', or 'he dumped his couch' (cumbersome/large single object).

Comment: But one of the examples from the dictionary was dumping a single dead body.

Comment: @Barmar - I understand your point. Yes, I think the dumping of the dead body is most similar to my example of the couch. It is a single object, but it is large or cumbersome enough that it's natural to use the verb 'dump'.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were clearer that "dump" can also be used for large objects in addition to large quantities.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, I've updated the answer to clarify this